# Call WP plugin function only if certain condition is met

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, wordpress

I am willing to use a GA plugin ([Google Analytics](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/), ex-yoast, now by Monsterinsights), but I would like the functions of this plugin to be called ONLY if ceartain conditions are met - in my case, if  users accept cookies. 
I found [EU Cookie Law](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eu-cookie-law/), a nice Italian plugin that provides  a simple way to execute some code, only if users opt in/

```
if ( function_exists('cookie_accepted') && cookie_accepted() ) {
    // Your code
}
```

Now, I could put GA code there, but I would like very much to benefit GA plugin advanced functions. But I wonder what would be the appropiate strategy (and code) to kind of "desactivate" GA plugin and activate it only "if cookies accepted".

Any idea?

Thanks,
Agnes

Comment: mmmm... I found a solution that doe snot incorportate GA plugin, but at least GA is not foired unless I get cookie consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the best solution I found is Tartaucitron - https://opt-out.ferank.eu/en/

Why is it better? With EU cookie laxw and other Italian plugins I found, GA code is not executed before people accept cookies... and will only be after they reload the page. 
Tarteaucitron makes is better legally as well as from a marketing point of view, because it enables:
- let user choose which cookeis / service he accepts
- activate scripts (including GA) on the same page, as soon as users accept.

But it takes some more efforts to install the script and get things work together.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm... I found a solution that does not incorportate GA plugin, but at least Google Analytics is not fired unless cookie consent is granted by user. 
It combines:

- [EU Cookie  Law](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eu-cookie-law/) plugin to get user consent
- [DuracellTomi Google Tag Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/) plugin  to call Google Tags (including GA) conditionnally,
- and a small edit just after the body tag that combines instruction of both plugins, :

  if ( function_exists('cookie_accepted') && cookie_accepted() ) {
      if ( function_exists( 'gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag' ) ) { gtm4wp_the_gtm_tag(); } 
  }